# Can Google robots see my S3 contents?

Tags: java, file, amazon-s3, google-search

I have an S3 bucket with confidential files for many users. I am sending emails to specific users containing a pre-signed URL to access their specific confidential file.

Are there security issues I am risking with Google robots being able to view these contents in these S3 pre-signed URLs? Can I do anything to prevent this?

Comment: Instead of worrying about a possible man-in-the-middle (Google), I would worry about the man who definitely can see the file contents (Amazon).

Comment: They are not that confidential either, but more concerned about other users seeing other users files. All the buckets are private. I just would not want them to end up in a publicly accessible place like Google.

Answer (score 0):

Private objects in Amazon S3 are not accessible by default.

You are using a **pre-signed URL**, which permits access to a specific object until a specific date/time.

Yes, if Google (or somebody else) got hold of the pre-signed URL, they would also be able to read the object. Therefore, **do not publicly reveal a pre-signed URL**. Think of it like a time-limited password -- if somebody had your password, they could act as if they were you. Therefore, keep your pre-signed URLs as safe as you would keep a password.